# cakePHP 3 link inside email view

Tags: email, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an issue build a link inside an email view, <s>it doesn't out put the URL i'm passing from the controller for some reason..</s>
the URL string that i'm passing to the view is missing the `http://domain` prefix

some action in usersController:

```
           $email = new Email(['gmail','transport'=>'gmail']);
           $email->template('recover', 'default')
                ->emailFormat('html')
                ->viewVars([
                    'username' => $user['username'],
                    'url' =>   '/users/resetpwd/u/'.$user['username'].'/t/'.$user['token']                      
                ])
                ->from(['mailer@domain.com' => 'My Site'])
                ->to('example@domain.com')
                ->subject('Password recovery')
                ->send()
```

recover.ctp:

```
<p>Welcome <b><?= $username; ?></b>,<br/>
 you requested a password change.<br/>
 To set a new password, please: <?php echo $this->Html->link('Click Here', $url, ['_full' => true,'escape' => true]); ?></p>
<?= $this->Html->image('banniere.gif', array('fullBase' => true));?><br/>
<p>This email was sent from <a href="http://cakephp.org">My Site</a></p>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's not your E-Mail application/provider/... that strips the URL for whatever reason? What exactly does `send()` return (note that it always returns a non-empty array, using it in an `if` statement is pretty pointless)?

Comment: you mean e-mail client? I tested 3 different clients and it's the same result: the link is not being generated.. added the email configuration in OP

Comment: I didn't asked for the E-Mail configuration, but for the return value of `send()`, which would show what exactly is being generated, so that people may be able to understand what is actually happening, and what exactly you mean by "_it doesn't out put the URL_".

Comment: in the original solution, the return of send() shows the following : `<a href="/app/controller/action/u/param1/t/param2" _full="1">` you can see that indeed it was missing the `http://domain` part.

Comment: I see, and that's pretty different from what you said in your qeustion, as it actually _is_ outputting the URL, just not in the format that you were expecting. Details like that should be in your question for people to be able to answer them properly.

Comment: Yes you are correct my bad if I wasn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that the URL is always a "full" one, then the proper solution here is `Router::url()`. That way you could even declare the URL in array format (which should normally be the preferred style anyways) without breaking things.

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;
// ...
<?= $this->Html->link('Click Here', Router::url($url, true), ['escape' => true]); ?>
```

Comment: Error: Class 'Router' not found. Am i missing something?

Comment: @user3813360 The `Router` class lives in the `Cake\Routing` namespace. You need to import it, or use the fully qualified path. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#quick-tour I've updated the answer to avoid obscurities.